# Update the date column in mysql

Tags: mysql, adapter

Im struggling in update the date format in mysql. Before that while retrieval from Mysql(using netbeans) of date using adapter the format was is like that

**"Birth_Date": "1990-10-11T00:00:00.000Z",**

Now i want to modify the column of Birthdate into  **1990-10-11**

i dont want rest of character .. guide me how to achieve this

Comment: This is very unclear. Your title says "update", but your first sentence says "insert", and the rest of the question seems to talk about the format during retrieval (which would actually be "select"). You don't give the datatype of the column, or if you do, it's not obvious that that's what you're doing.

Comment: @ruakh yeah sorry... now i edited my question please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't think you can change how MySql store is date type.

[Here's](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Format_dates_stored_in_MySQL-16641.html) a good article about it

> MySQL stores dates and timestamps in one format only: YYYY-MM-DD
>   hh:mm:ss. This is the format recommended by the International
>   Organization for Standardization (ISO).

Instead what you can do is when you do a select statement is to format the date using `Date_Format`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(birthDate, '%Y %m, %d') AS reg_formatted FROM yourtable
```

On the previous link you have all the formats possible

Comment: @MMarc ty for response .. im getting this error **Error code 1292, SQL state 22001: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'yyyy-mm-dd' for column 'Birth_Date' at row 1**

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. What datatype do you think `Birth_date` has? If you think it's a text type (e.g. `VARCHAR(50)`), then why are you passing it to `DATE_FORMAT`? If you think it's a date type (e.g. `DATE`), then why are you setting it to the result of `DATE_FORMAT`?

Comment: Read my thread onceagain **"Birth_Date": "1990-10-11T00:00:00.000Z" ** is not varchar format. its default format by mysql(using netbeans) now i want to change that format.